# product flat data no reindexing 1.9.1 magento errno: 121

Tags: product, error, reindex

We started having a product flat data re indexing error out of no where. We didnt install any new extensions, the only thing we have done was added new products.

running re-index via ssh we see the following error:

```
Product Flat Data index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'databasename.#sql-4e0_3486' (errno: 121)' in /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#5 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array)
#6 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(347): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#7 /public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(2731): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('ALTER TABLE `ca...')
#8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(815): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->addForeignKey('FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT...', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', 'CASCADE', 'CASCADE')
#9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(1389): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->prepareFlatTable(1)
#10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Flat/Indexer.php(296): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#11 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Indexer/Flat.php(350): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Flat_Indexer->reindexAll()
#12 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Indexer_Flat->reindexAll()
#13 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /public_html/shell/indexer.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /public_html/shell/indexer.php(215): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}
```

I tried truncating the  "catalog_product_flat_1 table" and then reindex but it still didnt work. I had to turn off "Use Flat Catalog Product" because the search box wasnt working. Please help.

Comment: Hi, please see ["How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?"](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your question.

Comment: did you get my last message? for some reason all the comments were removed from this page.

Comment: @rafaelOrtegaBueno did you get my response?

Comment: @rafael-ortega-bueno

Comment: i did  notice when i view the relationships under  catalog product flat 1, all the fields are blank

Comment: so i think the issue has to do with FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID

Comment: there is no foreign key relationship set. when i checked another magento site we have. we noticed there was a foreign key set.

Comment: when we try to set FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID as the foreign key we get the following error:#1025 - error on rename of (errno 152)

Comment: Hi Jackel, Do you have any custom module installed? Well all the tips I gave you, I tried locally with Magento clean without any problems.

Comment: we have several extensions (purchased) but nothing that was installed recently that would have affected this. at least that we know of.

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno I appreciate all of your help thus far. let me know what i can do next.

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno I even tried turning off "Use Flat Catalog Product" and deleting the table then reindex everything (no issue) then turning it on to reindex again and same issue.

Comment: @Jackel2017, Hard to say, just debugging your project. I do not have any problems with Magento clean locally in its version. There may be some custom module that is affecting this. Also check if there is any change in your Magento core.

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno , again we didnt make any changes and nothing has changed the magento core. This is what makes it very werid. Normally if we just installed something we can say that was the cause. In this case, we didnt. The only thing we did was add new products, which i also deleted to see if that would fix the problem. No luck. Like i mention before, i did not when looking at the relationship in the flat product table that nothing was set. In other magento installation it was. When i tried setting a foreign relationship manually it gave me that error i mention.

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno i have to think that is related to my problem. what are your thoughts?

Comment: im also currently in the process of uploading a backup(from 02-28-17) to a new database (test) to see if the relationships were there .

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632587/unable-to-drop-the-foreign-key

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno i looked at this previously but the problem i see is that there is no foreign key set on that table to begin with. When i try to set one it gives me the error i mention before.

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno , so i just finished uploading a backup of my database from 02-28-17 and i noticed that there is a relationship set with a foreign key "FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID" under structure of  catalog_product_flat_1. so something happen to this from 02-28-17 and 03-02-17. does this help identify my issue?

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno , i just imported that table from my backup database and this is the error i received: SQL query:

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--
--
-- Constraints for table `catalog_product_flat_1`
--
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_flat_1` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY ( `entity_id` ) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` ( `entity_id` ) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1005 - Can't create table 'databasebame.#sql-3c37_dfb7' (errno: 121)

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno , i just notice something odd. im viewing mysql process via WHM and i notice this:

Comment: 67014 cpses_sazRLCoAlW localhost NULL Sleep 74  NULL
67015 cpses_sazRLCoAlW localhost Database bname Query 0 update INSERT INTO `catalog_product_flat_1` (`entity_id`, `attribute_set_id`, `type_id`, `cost`, `created_a
I don’t know what user this is: cpses_sazRLCoAlW

This is not what we have set on local.xml plus I turned off , Use Flat Catalog Product until we fix this issue.

Comment: @Jackel2017, Interesting...   See these questions, The problem may have to do with this temporary user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511542/phpmyadmin-logging-me-as-a-new-cpses-localhost-user-every-time-how-can-i

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno , the user is just the session user when i goto mysql. i tried going to local host or root and same

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno , i did some more digging and this is interesting:

Comment: Foreign key search:

SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME, REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE CONSTRAINT_NAME = "FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID"

Comment: Result:
TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  CONSTRAINT_NAME  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME  REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME  
catalog_product_flat_1
entity_id
FK_CAT_PRD_FLAT_1_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID catalog_product_entity
entity_id

Comment: so its showing the foreign key is already assigned even though it doesnt show under catalog_product_flat_1

Comment: The output of “show create table `catalog_product_flat_1`” http://textuploader.com/dtsgi                  It doesn’t show any reference to the foreign key at all.

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno , thoughts?

Comment: @RafaelOrtegaBueno ???

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do a database dump, create a new database then import the dump and it fixed the problem. everything else didnt work. including optimize table function.